# Use of website / computer to setup mobile app?

Tags: mobile, onboarding

Suppose you have a **strictly** mobile app that requires the users to go through a setup process involving a fair amount of text input. Does it make sense to request the user to complete the setup on a computer (e.g. website) or should this happen within the mobile app or are there better alternatives?

E.g. An aggregator app takes blog, podcast, video subscriptions and download stuff for the user automatically for offline consumption. The user needs to set this up by providing feed URLs etc to the app. It's not easy to copy and paste on a device. Would it be more efficient to do this setup elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the smartphone is physically capable of collecting the URLs it needs to operate, there should be some mechanism within the app for performing that data collection.  It does not have to be the only mechanism for that data entry, but should still be present.  Otherwise, users, who do not have full size computers, would be  unable to use the program.

In a business analysis app which I wrote, I invite the user to enter volumous information directly into the phone, but also allow them to email themselves with a link to an online data-entry screen which could perform the same function.